# Como enviar dados para o banco de dados, comparar e exibir no site?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou fazendo um site onde irei adicionar a seção "Meu skate ideal", onde o usuário irá inserir seu nome, email, idade, altura, estilo e experiência (iniciante, intermediário ou profissional), feito isso o irá indicar qual o melhor estilo de skate de acordo com o perfil.

Minha dúvida é, como eu envio esses arquivos para o banco de dados, comparo-os e exibo o resultado?

Ex: "Seu skate ideal é o : tradicional"
    "Seu skate ideal é o : Longboard"

e por aí vai..

Há a possibilidade de fazer N's `if`, mas esta não é uma boa prática e para manutenção e uma possível expansão do código ficará ainda mais complicado.

```js
function calcula(){

 var nome = document.getElementById('nome').value;
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
 var altura = document.getElementById('altura').value;
 var peso = document.getElementById('peso').value;

 var sel_estilo = document.getElementById('estilo');
 var valor_estilo = sel_estilo.options[sel_estilo.selectedIndex].value;

 var sel_nivel = document.getElementById('nivel');
 var valor_nivel = sel_nivel.options[sel_nivel.selectedIndex].value;
  
 var calc = altura * peso;

     if((valor_estilo == 2) && (calc>100) && (valor_nivel == 1)){
       alert('Longboard Cruising');
      }
 }
```

```css
html, body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#principal{
 width:25%;
 height:110px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

input, select{
 border:none;
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 border-sizing: border-box;
 box-shadow: 7px 4px 14px 1px rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div id="principal">
 <center>
 <input type="text" id="nome" placeholder="Digite seu nome"><br>
 <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Digite seu email"><br>
 <input type="text" id="idade" placeholder="Digite sua idade"><br>
 <input type="number" id="altura" placeholder="Digite sua altura"><br>
 <input type="number" id="peso" placeholder="Digite seu peso"><br>
 <select id="estilo">
  <option value="selecione"></option>
  <option value="1" id="mano">Manobras radicais</option>
  <option value="2" id="velo">Passeios tranquilos em baixa velocidade</option>
 </select>
 <select id="nivel">
  <option value="selecione"></option>
  <option value="1" id="ini">Iniciante</option>
  <option value="2" id="int">Intermediário</option>
  <option value="3" id="pro">Profissional</option>
 </select> <br>
 <input type="submit" id="enviar" value="Enviar" onclick="calcula()">
 </center>
 </div>
```

Este é um esboço que fiz caso eu fizesse com 541618 `if's` rsrs

Como eu posso lançar esses dados para o banco de dados, "fazer os `if's`" e retornar o valor para o usuário/site?

> OBS 1: Obviamente, não quero o código pronto, mas pelo menos um caminho por onde seguir..
>   OBS 2: O cálculo utilizado é apenas um exemplo. A lógica que irei usar é mais elaborada.
>   OBS 3: Estou aberto a soluções em JQuery também.

Answer (score 1):

Caso você não tenha intenção de usar um framework para fazer o back-end(o que eu recomendo utilizar), você poderia fazer a conexão como neste [exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857670/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-javascript-in-the-browser).

```
var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection") ;

var connectionstring="Data Source=<server>;Initial Catalog=<catalog>;User ID=<user>;Password=<password>;Provider=SQLOLEDB";

connection.Open(connectionstring);
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

rs.Open("SELECT * FROM table where ideade = " + idade + " and altura like " + altura, connection);
rs.MoveFirst
if(!rs.eof)
{
   document.write("Seu skate ideal é o " + rs.fields("skate"));
   rs.movenext;
}

rs.close;
connection.close;
```